# encoding in Swift 3

Tags: swift, nscoding

I have the following code which I'm trying to put into Swift 3. The line `super.encodeWithCoder(aCoder)` is giving problems. Whatever I do gives an error.

```
import Foundation
class ToDo: Task {
var done: Bool

@objc required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    self.done = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("done") as! Bool
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}

@objc override func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder) {
    aCoder.encodeObject(done, forKey: "done")
    super.encodeWithCoder(aCoder)
}

init(name: String, done: Bool) {
    self.done = done
    super.init(name: name)
}
}
```

I'm trying to convert to Swift 3

I have this

```
import Foundation

class ToDo: Task {
var done: Bool

@objc required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    self.done = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "done") as! Bool
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}

@objc override func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
    aCoder.encode(done, forKey: "done")
    // THis line gives an error
    super.encode(with aCoder)

}

init(name: String, done: Bool) {
    self.done = done
    super.init(name: name)
}

}
```

The line 
`super.encodeWithCoder(aCoder)`
gives an error . Swift gives no prompt and a search has given no answers.

Edit in response to comments
The original code "super.encodeWithCoder(aCoder)" gives the error Value of type 'Task' has no member 'encodeWithCoder'

super.encode(with aCoder)  gives error   Expected ';' separator

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: While odd coding, that's likely because I'm unfamiliar with overriding this - I always thought that only views created in IB use init(coder:). That said, two things jump out at me: (1) You didn't post details of what kind of error you are getting. (2) I could see a build error because you have some code before calling super.ecode(with: coder). BONUS: I just now saw your code is also missing the colon in that line. I'm very sure that definitely won't build.

Comment: "The line `super.encodeWithCoder(aCoder)` gives an error". That line doesn't exist in your Swift 3 example. Do you mean your call to `super.encode(with aCoder)` is failing to compile? As dfd points out, that wouldn't compile because it has to be `super.encode(with: aCoder)`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason that the app crashes is that you use a `decodeObject()` function for a Bool.

Changing the code to the correct functions yields:

```
@objc required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    self.done = aDecoder.decodeBool(forKey: "done")
}

@objc override func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
 aCoder.encode(done, forKey: "done")
}
```

Comment: This works but I had to add     super.init(coder: aDecoder) to not have an error message

Comment: Ill update answer accordingly. Havent had an error not using it O:)